# Node.JS Odd Behavior Receiving Post Data

Tags: xml, node.js, http, rest, post

I am sending XML data in a post request to my node.js server.  The server is setup to accept post and have been running tests without an issue through CURL.  Now I am attempting to get this same data through a POST request from multiple REST clients and through a plugin called Postman in Chrome.  The end goal is to receive data to the server when an EXE file is kicked off.

The issue that I am running into is that the XML data seems to come in and stop at 1439 characters (the total characters is closer to 3900).  It then receives the full 3900 characters.  The issue is that the XML parser is seeing this as a bad XML doc as the first 1439 characters is killing the syntax.  I have continued to test, but do not see why 1439 characters are sent and then followed up by the full 3900 characters.

Furthermore this doesn't appear to occur all the time.  I have tested from these sources multiple times in a row and this behavior only seems to occur at random.  The full code that I am using is listed below.

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
if(req.method=='POST'){
    var body='';
req.on('data', function (data) {
    body +=data;
    body = body.toString();
    var xmlDoc = libxmljs.parseXml(body));
    var status = xmlDoc.get('//Status').text();
    var ticket = xmlDoc.get('//Incident_ID').text();
    console.log(status + " " + ticket);
});
req.on('end', function(){

});
}
else if(req.method=='GET'){

    var url_parts = url.parse(req.url,true);

        spectrum['alarm'] = url_parts.query.AlarmID;
        spectrum['troubleshooter'] = url_parts.query.TroubleShooter;
        spectrum['title'] = url_parts.query.AlarmTitle;
        spectrum['date'] = url_parts.query.CreationDate;
        spectrum['model'] = url_parts.query.ModelName;
        spectrum['mac'] = url_parts.query.MAC;
        spectrum['ip'] = url_parts.query.IP;
        spectrum['severity'] = url_parts.query.Severity;
        spectrum['knowledge'] = url_parts.query.KnowledgeID;


    console.log("Contacted");

    console.log("got varabiles");
    eventEmitter.emit("gotVariables", spectrum);        
}

res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
res.end("Request Submitted");

}).listen(1234, "localhost");
```

I am completely stuck as to why this is occurring and can't understand why it would be happening at random as it is.  As it stands it only appears to happen with long data.  When I send a simple 500 character XML doc it runs fine 100% of the time.

I did notice when using CURL that there is a header that says Expect: 100-continue.  I have attempted to put this into the headers of the other requests to no avail.  I may not be using it correctly or something may not be being handled in the node.js, but I'm not sure.

Hopefully this provides enough detail into what I'm attempting to do.  I appreciate any assistance in troubleshooting this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data` event is fired multiple times with chunks of data as they come in, you need to wait for them all to have been received by waiting to parse in the `end` event.

```
var chunks = [];
req.on('data', function (data) {
  chunks.push(data);
});
req.on('end', function(){
  var body = Buffer.concat(chunks).toString();

  var xmlDoc = libxmljs.parseXml(body));
  var status = xmlDoc.get('//Status').text();
  var ticket = xmlDoc.get('//Incident_ID').text();
  console.log(status + " " + ticket);
});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Thanks for posting this I really appreciate it.  I had trouble finding any data on this so wasn't sure where the parsing should go, but this makes complete sense.  

Just to make sure I get what is going on is that you setup an array and push the data to that array as it comes in in the first function.  Then all data is moved to the second function and basically just grabbing those chunks putting them together and pushing to strings?  The only part I don't understand is what the Buffer is doing.  Will have to do some research on that.  Thanks again!

Comment: @ThomDuran Correct! Each `data` object is a Node `Buffer`, not a string, so when you want to join all of the pieces together, you need to use `Buffer`'s `concat` to get one single `Buffer`, the convert that to a string.

Comment: @loganfsmyth :I tried the same approach but whenever i hit the url throw code the server throws me 500 internal server error.I am stuck here any idea will be much helpful

Comment: @AmandaG Please post a new question, and I'd be happy to help.

Comment: @loganfsmyth : Please find the link for my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16668941/posting-xml-to-a-url-in-nodejs