# Posting xml to a url in nodejs

Tags: xml, node.js, http, client

I am developing a client program to hit a post url and get the response from it
Below is my code

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var postData = "<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'utf-8'?><REST><Contact>aa</Contact></REST>";

fs.readFile('SampleData.xml', 'utf8', function (err, fileData)
{
if (err)
{
    return console.log(err);
}
else
{
    console.log("\n Data : \n\n" +fileData);

    var options = {
        host: 'kkk',
        port: 1,
        path: '/root',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type" : 'application/xml'
        }
    };

    var reqClient = http.request(options, function(res)
    {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function (chunk)
        {
            //console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
        });
    });

    //Posts the data to the Server
    reqClient.write(postData);
    reqClient.end();

    reqClient.on('response', function (response)
    {
        response.on('data', function (chunk)
        {
            //console.log(response.statusCode + "\n");
            //console.log(response.headers);
            console.log("\n" + 'RESPONSE: ' + chunk);
        });
    });
    }
 });
```

I tried reading the xml data from the file plus i also passed the data directly in req.write.Both the times its just throwing me error because the xml is passing as a string.I need a solution to convert the string to xml before passing.I am stuck here.Any help will be  much helpful.

I tried a new approach too please find below the code

```
var http = require('http');
var body='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'+
'<REST><ListOfLN_Interface>'+
'<Contact>123304</Contact>'+
'</ListOfLN_Interface></REST>';



var postRequest = {
host: "hhhh",
path: "/Contact",
port: 01,
method: "POST",
headers: {

    'Content-Type': 'application/xml',
    'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(body)
}
}; 

var buffer = "";

var req = http.request( postRequest , function( res )    {

console.log( res.statusCode );
console.log( res.headers);
var buffer = "";
var chunks = [];
res.on('data', function (data) {
    chunks.push(data);
});
res.on('end', function(){
    var body1 = Buffer.concat(chunks).toString();

    //var xmlDoc = libxmljs.parseXml(body);
   // var status = xmlDoc.get('//Status').text();
    //var ticket = xmlDoc.get('//Incident_ID').text();
    console.log(body1);
});
 //res.on( "data", function( data ) { buffer = buffer + data; } );
// res.on( "end", function( data ) { console.log( buffer ); } );

});

req.write( body );
req.end();
```

This threw me 500 internal server error.Dont  know where am goin wrong.

Comment: If it's giving a 500 error, does it say anything about what the error is? 500 means there was an error on the server that you are connecting to, possibly because the data you are sending is wrong.

Comment: But when i try to hit the same url using the same xmldata from a simple rest client it is giving me response.

Comment: Something about what you are sending with the rest client must be slightly different then. Why in your first example do you have spaces around the processing instruction attributes, and no `<ListOfLN_Interface>` element?